# Millennial Media and AdWhirl for Android

Tags: android, adwhirl, millennial-media

I have to add ads to an app.

97% admob 
 3% millennial media

I tried to set the values to 50%. After that I regognize that I get an error everytime AdWhirl trys to show Millennial Media Ads.

```
04-26 21:28:59.099: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(12981): Rotating Ad
04-26 21:28:59.099: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(12981): Dart is <81.77319307774556> of <100.0>
04-26 21:28:59.109: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(12981): Showing ad:
04-26 21:28:59.109: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(12981):     nid: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
04-26 21:28:59.109: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(12981):     name: millennial
04-26 21:28:59.109: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(12981):     type: x
04-26 21:28:59.109: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(12981):     key: xxxxx
04-26 21:28:59.109: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(12981):     key2: 
04-26 21:28:59.109: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(12981): Valid adapter, calling handle()
04-26 21:28:59.179: INFO/MillennialMediaAdSDK(12981): No incomplete downloads.
04-26 21:28:59.219: INFO/MillennialMediaAdSDK(12981): Last ad name is null. Call for new ad.
04-26 21:28:59.229: INFO/MillennialMediaAdSDK(12981): Making ad request
04-26 21:28:59.549: INFO/MillennialMediaAdSDK(12981): Millennial ad return failed. Zero content length returned.
04-26 21:28:59.549: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(12981): Millennial failure
04-26 21:28:59.569: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(12981): Showing ad:
04-26 21:28:59.569: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(12981):     nid: xxxxxxxxxxx
04-26 21:28:59.569: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(12981):     name: admob
04-26 21:28:59.569: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(12981):     type: x
04-26 21:28:59.569: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(12981):     key: xxxx
04-26 21:28:59.569: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(12981):     key2: 
04-26 21:28:59.569: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(12981): Valid adapter, calling handle()
```

I have try 2 other Millennial IDs. (Just by replacing the ID in AdWhirl and reinstall the app)

The first ID : 28911 (http://wiki.millennialmedia.com/index.php/Android#XML_Layout)
This one works everytime.

The second ID is from an testapp I create in Millennial.
This one ist strage. Sometimes it works and sometimes it fails. (At the beginning it fails everytime just like the original ID)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it was a Bug from the ad network. A new update of the app doesn't contain the problem.

Comment: I am also seeing this 'Zero Content Length Returned' error, but it only happens on one out of my two apps. Both are using the same MM Android SDK vesion 4.5.

What does it mean exactly? No ad fill, or some other server side error?

Answer (score 2):

I work on the developer team at Millennial and noticed your post. We’d be happy to help you troubleshoot the error you are seeing. From the information you’ve provided it looks like it might be a placement configuration problem, but let’s definitely take a look and get it resolved for you. Please reach out directly with your APID and any additional details here: http://developer.millennialmedia.com/contact.php

Thanks,
Millennial Media Developer Team